# Best design pattern for multiple options in winforms app?

Tags: design-patterns, oop

I have a winforms app which performs actions (logging into a site and performing UI tests), but with a number of selected options such as logging in via basic auth or normal forms auth, as well as the browser type, etc.

Is the specification design pattern best suited to this? Are there any other good strategies?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems the best design pattern for you is [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Have all the varied parts in an external configuration, and then your program should read the configuration at boot, and init just the chosen options according to the configuration.